# How to increase pointer's pointer value in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I've been reading how the pointer works in C++ and I tried to mess with it a little but the program stopped working.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char a[] = "Hello";
  char * b = a;
  char ** c = &b;

  cout << *(b+1) << endl;
  //cout << **(c+2) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If the commented line is not commented, the program stops working with error code: 0xC0000005. Am I doing something wrong or is this some sort of bug?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `cout << *(*c+2) << endl;` you mean...

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah, that did it. Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need all the stuff that it does. `'\n'` starts a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
char a[] = "Hello";
char * b = a;
```

You are taking advantage of array to pointer decay. So now `b` points to `a[0]`. That is, `b` holds the address of `a[0]`

and then

```
char ** c = &b;
```

`c` now points to the *address* of `b`, which is itself a pointer. c holds the address of `b`, which holds the address of `a` (see why people hate pointers now?)

If you want to access `a[0]` from `c`, you first need to de-reference it:

```
*c
```

which gives `b`, and then we need to dereference *that* to get back to `a[0]`:

```
*(*c)
```

If you want to use pointer arithmetic to access `a[1]`, you want to increment `b`, so:

*c+1

and now we have the address of `a[1]`, and if we want to print that, we need to dereference again:

```
*(*c+1)
```

You made the mistake of incrementing the address of `b` instead of the address of `a[0]` when you said:

```
**(c+2)
```

`c` held the address of `b`, not `a`, so incrementing on that will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

`c` points to the address of `b` on the current stack frame.

`c + 2` points to some location on the stack frame, thanks to pointer arithmetic.

`*(c + 2)` You then access this location, taking unspecified bytes there as an address.

`**(c + 2)` Now you attempt to access said unspecified address, and luckily for you, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay let's try again.

a is a pointer to the first element in the array, in this case "H".
c is a pointer to the address of b which is also a pointer to the first element.

When you increment c by 2, you are moving that pointer forward by two. So the memory address goes forward by two, but c is just a pointer to a and not a itself, so you're in unknown territory. Instead, what would likely work (untested):

```
cout<<*(*c+1)<<endl;
```

This dereferences c, so you get b (or a, same thing), you increment this pointer by 1, which stays in the array, and then you dereference again to access the value.!

Answer (score 0):

`&b + 2` is not a valid pointer.

For simplicity, let's assume that a pointer is just one `char` wide (our memory is very, very small).

Assume that `a` is stored at the address 10, `b` at 20, and `c` at 21.

`char* b = a;` is the same as `char* b = &a[0];` – it stores the location of the array's first element (10) in `b`.
`char**c = &b` stores the location of `b` (20) in `c`.

It looks like this:

```
  a                                       b    c
  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20   21   22...
| H | e | l | l | o | 0 |   |   |   |   | 10 | 20 |
```

It should be clear from this image that `c + 2` is 22, which is not a valid address.
Dereferencing it is undefined and anything can happen – your crashing was just good luck.

If you were expecting the first `l` in `"Hello"`, it's located at `a[2]`, which is `b[2]` (or `*(b + 2)`), which is `(*c)[2]` (or `*(*c + 2)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[] = "Hello";
char * b = a;
char ** c = &b;
```

a and b point to the beginning of char array having "Hello" as its characters.

So, lets starting at memory location 0x100 Hello is stored.

a is pointer so it stores an address.

a and b both store this values 0x100. But their addresses are something else. Lets say address of a is 0x200 and address of b is 0x300.

c is also pointer. So it stores address of b.
So, c stores address 0x300 as its values.

c+1 = 0x304

c+2 = 0x308

*c     : You want to access value stored at 0x300, which is the address of b.

*(c+1) : You want to access address 0x304

*(c+2) : You then access 0x308, taking unspecified bytes there as an address.

**(c+2) : Dereference the address 0x308. It may or may not be address of pointer variable. So, dereferencing may be undefined operation.